# Fat Free Framework getting started error

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I've create a first .php file with [fat free framework](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/) but it is not working

Contents of file:

```
<?php
  require_once("../fatfree/lib/base.php");
  F3::route('GET /','home');
    function home() 
    {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
  F3::run();
?>
```

I'm getting a 404 error

Comment: Which URL are you using to access your page? Keep in mind that the example won't work if you don't access it as `http://yourserver/` (i.e. in the server root): http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/page/getting-started/cant-get-the-example-running

Comment: Ya of course, i'm using 127.0.0.1, localhost

Comment: when I'm removing all the codes and placing echo "Hello", it is ok

Comment: @Noor Is this your `index.php` file or some other file?

Comment: Please share your .htaccess settings. This is a critical config element to make that index.php work.

Comment: What is your exact 404 error? You .htaccess file might need a RewriteBase.

Answer (score 2):

The routing engine can't call loose functions like that. You should either make your function a method of a class like this:

```
<?php
  require_once("../fatfree/lib/base.php");
  F3::route('GET /','foo->home');
  class foo{
    public function home() 
    {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
  }
  F3::run();
?>
```

OR turn your home function into an anonimous function like this:

```
<?php
  require_once("../fatfree/lib/base.php");
  F3::route('GET /',function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
  );
  F3::run();
?>
```